# Dart: Inherit some of the public methods privately

Tags: flutter, dart, polymorphism

I want to inherit a class, but I want to make some of its methods private, which allows mutation of the object. I do not want to override those methods, as that will make them still accessible and cause a runtime error. I want something like this:-

```dart
class BaseClass {
  //...
  void update() {/*Implementation*/}
  void read() {/*Implementation*/}
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  //...
  void read() {/*Implementation*/}
}

int main() {
  final first = BaseClass(), second = ChildClass();
  first.update(); //Works
  second.update(); //Error: Method does not exist.
}
```

Comment: This is not possible and violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  If a `ChildClass` is-a `BaseClass`, it must be substitutable for a `BaseClass`.  If you control both classes, I suggest inverting the inheritance hierarchy instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want it possible. The entire point of extending classes is that child classes can access all public methods of the superclass. You might want to use composition instead. That would be something like:

```
class BaseClass {
  //...
  void update() {/*Implementation*/}
  void read() {/*Implementation*/}
}

class ChildClass {
  BaseClass _baseClass
  //...
  void read() { _baseClass.read() }
}
```

Comment: Well as we can inherit classes publically, or privately in C++, I was looking for an alternative for something similar in dart.

Comment: @Vishnubly The point is that we can do this in Dart: `BaseClass object = ChildClass()` . We can then send this `object` into methods that expect a `BaseClass` object. But for this to be supported, we must expect that our `object` provide access to all methods defined in `BaseClass`. So it is impossible for `ChildClass` to hide a method and still be compatible with `BaseClass`.